How to enable automatic color cycling for Arc patches in matplotlib?
In this Python 3.12 script:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Arc

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for a1 in range(0, 360, 20):
  ax.add_patch(Arc((0, 0), 10, 10, theta1=a1, theta2=a1+20))
  
ax.set_aspect('equal')  
ax.autoscale_view()  
plt.show()

I would like to see each Arc having a different color, sequentially provided by the default color cycler. How to do it?

Preferably, I would like to have implicit color cycling, i.e. without specifying color= parameter.

By "the default color cycler" I assume you mean the tab10 colormap (shown here). You can set the color parameter of the Arc. Since you have more than 10 arcs but the colormap only has 10 colors, you can use the modulo operator to cycle back around.
for i, a1 in enumerate(range(0, 360, 20)):
  ax.add_patch(Arc((0, 0), 10, 10, theta1=a1, theta2=a1+20, color=plt.cm.tab10(i%10)))

Result:


This is definitely an option, but I meant an implicit color cycling. I will edit my question to make it clear.

I'm not sure you can force a Patch to use the default cycler, without giving some extra input to the Patch (in this case, your Arc).
First, we need to get the default cycler; we can get this from the rcParams; the key we are interested in is axes.prop_cycle.
We can then iterate over the cycler using itertools.cycle in the same loop as your segments, using zip. There are some useful examples on the cycler documentation page.
Putting it all together:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Arc
from itertools import cycle

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Get the default cycler (alternatively, you could define your own here)
cycler = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle']

# Iterate over angles and the cycler
for a1, sty in zip(range(0, 360, 20), cycle(cycler)):
    # Pass items from the cycler into Arc as kwargs
    ax.add_patch(Arc((0, 0), 10, 10, theta1=a1, theta2=a1+20, **sty))

ax.set_aspect('equal')  
ax.autoscale_view()  
plt.show()


